# Нужен ли предлог "с" после запятой?

Tags: предлоги

"Нет интересных постов, с которыми можно было бы поделиться." или " Нет интересных постов,которыми можно было бы поделиться."

Answer (score 2):

А вы чем-то делитесь с постами? :)

Конечно, предлог не нужен.